# CSS - Font appears bolder on devices with higher dpi

Tags: html, css

I have been testing my web page on different devices an the text appears bolder on devices with higher device pixel ratios (iPhone, for example). I have tested this on the chrome emulator as well : The text looks perfect at DPR 1 and appears much bolder at DPR 2.

**At DPR 1**

[image]

**AT DPR 2**

[image]

Is there any way to fix or reduce the effect? Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="section" id="section3">
  <h1>Projects</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*to fix safari bold font*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, strong, b {
  font-weight: 400;
}

#section4 h1,#section3 h1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Graphik-Semibold, Roboto;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
  top: 3.7%;
}
```

This is the most relevant code, rest is aligning and media queries for font size.

Comment: Wondering if this is only on browser debug or if this is the case on mobile devices with higher DPR

Comment: Have you already tried playing around with the text-rendering property? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering Also, you could use a pixel ratio media query to force a less-bold font at higher pixel density: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: @Persijn - I have checked on actual physical devices, the text appears bold

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  b {
    font-weight: 600;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  b {
    font-size: 400;
  }
}
```

You might need to change some of the numbers though to get the result you want this is just an example.

There isn't really any other way to do this that I know of because font-weight is really always different even if the number is the same. Plus it's not really that big of a difference on the DPR 2.0

It looks good :)

Comment: This would be a good answer if you used media queries to select the DPR like `min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` and not screen size since that's calculated using DPR.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I would know what else to do

Comment: The `device-pixel-ratio` media query is being deprecated. You should use resolution instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-moz-device-pixel-ratio